# Rundeck -> how can we pass the captured Key Value Data into the mail Template

Tags: rundeck

How can we pass the captured Key-Value Data (Log filter) into the mail Template,

For example, my current template looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>create Heap dump</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>
       Hi,<br><br>
       ${option.Description} <br>
       ${logoutput.data}<br><br>
       Regards,<br>
       Game World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently i am not able to pass any captured value like ${data.value}. Is there anything i am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to export that data value variable to a global one and then use it in your notifications.

1. The first step print some text, with a filter, capture the data value and it's s stored in a `${data.MYDATA}`.
2. The second step takes that data variable and creates a global one using the "Global Variable" Step.
3. You can use that global variable in any notification as `${export.myvariable}`.

Take a look at this job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: ea07f41a-71b4-4ed9-91fb-6113de996e48
  loglevel: INFO
  name: TestJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  notification:
    onsuccess:
      plugin:
        configuration:
          authentication: None
          body: ${export.myglobal}
          contentType: application/json
          method: POST
          remoteUrl: https://any/webhook/url
          timeout: '30000'
        type: HttpNotification
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  schedules: []
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: env
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            regex: ^(USER)\s*=\s*(.+)$
          type: key-value-data
    - configuration:
        export: myglobal
        group: export
        value: ${data.USER*}
      nodeStep: false
      type: export-var
    - exec: echo ${export.myglobal}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: ea07f41a-71b4-4ed9-91fb-6113de996e48
```

Using the HTTP notification (in the body section) you can see the value (same for your case using email notification).