# Capture log messages dynamically within a custom plugin

Tags: logging, filter, plugins, rundeck

I am writing a custom rundeck plugin that executes a remote command.
The executed command will print out some messages, that I need to interpret within my plugin, and based on this output do a certain action.

Thus is it possible that I add a log listener at runtime to capture those logs within my plugin?

I am aware that the user can predefine a list of LogFilterPlugin for his step, but in my case I need to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the opuput on a exported variable to use in the job or/and notifications, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72364741/10426011).